# Какой-то непонятный ползунок

Tags: дефект, дизайн, новогодние-шляпы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть подозрение, что это из-за радужной шляпы.

Comment: А скроллить им можно?

Answer (score 3):

Да, это из-за шляпы, у меня было такое же. Язык слишком длинный и выходит за пределы ячейки. Надо шляпу или снять или уменьшить.